# htaccess is not working properly

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have a problem in htaccess file when i want to write a code of url rewriting in my htaccess file. I want to change this url `"quotewebster.com/topics.php?topic_id=12"` into this

```
"quotewebster.com/topics/12/"
```

I write this a code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule    ^topics/([0-9]+)/?$    topics.php?topic_id=$1    [NC,L]
```

And it is running fine, But a problem arises when i click any topic it goes to the right page and URL also rewrite but when i want to change the topic and again click on any topic then the url previous topic id embed with the new topic id and URL is something like that

```
"quotewebster.com/topics/12/topics/13/"
```

I don't understand it why it is happening. Please help me in this case. And sorry for bad english.

Thanks

Comment: try `RewriteRule    ^/topics/([0-9]+)/?$    topics.php?topic_id=$1    [NC,L]`

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm fairly confident that that has nothing to do with the rewrite but with your code generating relative paths.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the urls in your page are not written correct. My guess: <a href=topics/xx> instead of <a href=/topics/xx>

Comment: I am writing the url like that <a href=topics/xx>

Comment: Should i write it in that way? <a href=/topics/xx>

Comment: @user2226181 Yes, that'd make the path relative to the root of the server instead of relative to the last URL used (which is `quotewebster.com/topics/12/`)

Comment: Thankyou  Joachim Isaksson. Its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely with the way you generate your urls.

Make sure that your links start with a slash:

```
href="/topics/12"
```

not

```
href="topics/12"
```